# Application Development for Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

Is it possible to create programs in Java and run on both Linux and Windows? 
What i mean is. is it possible "write once and run everywhere" . If not possible , is it possible to convert program from one platform to another by making minimum modification (ie, windows to Linux and vice versa)?
If that not possible,
Is it possible to create  programs in a particular style  which enables the programmer to convert it into , windows platform or to Linux platform
Even If this not possible is it possible to create new type of virtual machine system or something make it possible

even if none of the idea works , what is the biggest barrier?  why it is not possible in a easy manner ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you can run java programs on windows an linux, and you can make cross platform programs in java as long as your operating system has the java runtime on it, if not... it won't run. You don't need to code different for windows and for linux in java, maybe just some minor adjustments in the program.You really didn't know that?

Anyway, because of your questions i suppose you are a little kid (i hope i'm not wrong) and my advice to you is that you begin by studing the java basics because your question is too basic... and sincerely, change you attitude, it will be good for you.

Comment: If that the case why , its not possible to run various games in linux ? why various programs have linux version mac version and windows version .why all of them wasting their time .they just have to say why do not you install jvm .and  can run any where . i am not talking about simple programs  , i know about those i am talking about graphical intense programs , for wide range of people not some niche program for particular use

Comment: It is possible to run games in linux. If the game is made in Java and you have the java runtime in linux... then you should not have problems to run it. But normally games are NOT written in java, usually they are written natively (with c++ for example) for windows os. But now, with Steam OS lnux is getting more and more native games...

Comment: Native code is faster than byte code (if coded correctly, of course.. it could be worst if you don't know what you are doing!)... that's why games are usually made usually in c++ and not java...

Comment: @ nelson So why they choose C++ ?performance issues ? or just convenience ? or habit ?when linux created  why they do not think about it ?                                                                                                                    what would be the worst ? it wont run right ? your system ,do not burst  into  flames or not turn into some flush eating zombies right ? its only a bug ,  just fix it

Comment: performance issues...  that's why... i don't think is convenience, because coding in interpreted languajes (think java, c#, for example) usually is more convenient in terms of secure code . Maybe that could change in future... take a look at .NET NATIVE, for example, it uses C#....

Comment: So What you mean is , By using  Java ,its possible to create any programs for any platform with great efficiency and security right ?                                                                                                         knowing How much is enough in Java ? I know some basics in java and I am trying to code GUI , i could see its potential but how far i could go ? when i reach a  saturation level ? how much education and experience is required ? I got some ideas , but i'm not sure , whether its possible or not .that's why i want to be sure. i do not want my effort go in vain.

Comment: Well, if you go with java, then the best actual option for GUI is javafx 8... but be warned... you have a long way in front of you, you will have to study, practice and be patient... very patient. If you want the short way, then you have other options on the internet, but you will never have the control and flexibility to make your programs as you really want.

Comment: how long is short enough ?                                                                                                                    i want my programs to be exactly what i want. Like java PHp is the best for web  development right ?

Comment: How long... well, it depends... everyone is different, but i could bet no less than one year. If you want to go for the web, for client web development, it will be better for you to learn javascript, jquery, and html 5. They rule on the internet....

Comment: thanx for you patient replies. have a nice day :) bye

Comment: Thank you, I told you to be patient jajaja... have a nice day.